# JQuery - Cross Domain Ajax call for JSON file without JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, same-origin-policy

I am trying to access a URL from a different domain, lets say ***www.url-one.com***, that only serves up a JSON file and cannot serve up a JSONP file. This does not work for me using JQuery's ajax() function.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://url-two.com'+sample,
        async : false,
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        success : function(data) {
            // Some Other Code
        }
     }
```

What can I do to work around the same origin policy without relying on JSONP? 
Thanks in advance - I am having major problems with the proxy thing but I heard that it's possible.

Comment: I really need detailed help setting up the proxy because I have never done that before

Comment: If you do not have access to the remote server, there is no way around the same origin policy.

Comment: Additionally, there are many questions related to setting up a proxy page on this site. What server are you running on and in what language? Without this information we will not be able to help you at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to do this, below i will mention 3 i have used myself in the past.

The most common is to use [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Basically the server which hosts the json file (lets call it server1), will need to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header correctly to allow the other server (lets call it server2) to access it.

If you don't wish to or can't use CORS you can do one of the 2 following:

1: use a re-write rule on server2 to redirect traffic for a certain path from server2 to server1.

2: use a serverside proxy on server2 to fetch the json file.

Setting either of these things up is completely dependent on your server setup, and i can't help you with that bit.